# The numbers that can be written as the sum of squares of two **natural** numbers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

It's easy to solve for sum of two squares.but it becomes hard when we want numbers that can written as sum of squares of two natural number.For example given number $n$ can be written as the sum of two natural numbers if...

**My Attempt**:I see that which numbers don't follow the condition I saw that some of squares don't follow that for example 9 or 16 but some of them follow that for example 25.

Comment: Is there a "squares" missing from the question title? Is $0$ a natural number for you?

Comment: Natural numbers: ${0,1,2,3...}$ or ${1,2,3...}$?

Comment: The set of numbers that can be represented as $a^2+b^2$ is given by the numbers whose prime divisors occuring with odd multiplicity are $\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: no if zero isn't a natural number

Comment: If you are looking for the list of squares which can be written as the sum of squares, you are in essence looking for [pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).  If you are looking for the prime numbers which can be expressed as the sum of two squares, see [fermat's theorem on the sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

Comment: See D.H. Cox, *Primes of the form $x^2+n y^2$*.

Comment: but these are just primes

Comment: I'm looking for a formula not set of numbers

Comment: Then you need to clarify what exactly your question is.  Is your question "*given a number $n$, determine if and if so how it can be written as the sum of squares?*"

Comment: "It's easy to solve for sum of two squares.but it becomes hard when we want numbers that can written as sum of squares of two natural number." ??? As $(-x)^2 = x^2$ it seems to me to be *exactly* the same question.

Comment: Yes but zero makes it hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well known which numbers can be written as sum of two squares of two integers, wlog nonnegative integers.

If you want to restrict yourself to sum of two positive integers, then you just would like to check numbers of the form $n^2+0^2$, i.e. squares, which cannot be written as sum of two positive squares. In other words, you want to find all squares $a^2$ which cannot be written as $b^2+c^2$, for some positive integer $b,c$. Equivalently, you want to check all Pitagorean triple and, again, the parametric form of all Pitagorean triplets $(a,b,c)$ are well known.

Then, all the positive integers $n$ which can be written as sum of two positive squares are those satisfying:

(i) if $n$ is not a squares and $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ divides $n$ then the $p$-adic valuation of $n$ is even;

(ii) if $n$ is a square, then it has to be of the form $k(a^2+b^2)$, for some positive integers $k,a,b$.

The second condition (ii) states that $n^2$ is sum of two positive squares if and only if there exists a divisor of $n$ which is a sum of two positive squares. Now, if that divisor is not a squares itself, then you can use again condition (i).

Comment: Ok but this isn't what I want I want a formula that founds these kinds of numbers

Comment: Then your question was unclear. Anyway I added what you asked here

Comment: but your second conditon is like that trying.That's not a good way to know it can written or not

Comment: Oh yes that's right